# Identify bitcoin transaction MySQL Query problems

Tags: mysql, api, transactions, bitcoin

I have a user table holding user datas

```
++ id  | username | btc_recive_address++
----------------------------------------
++  1  | myuser   | 123kahpoiq31328   ++
```

order table

```
 ++ order_id  | user_id | amount  | order_timestamp
 ------------------------------------------------------
 ++ h6765-a1s | 1       | 0.1 BTC | 2014-04-09 13:21:34 
 ------------------------------------------------------
 ++ kzg765-a1 | 1       | 0.1 BTC | 2014-04-09 17:11:23
```

and collector table which retrieves data from bitcoin API( here I identify sender with btc_recive_address)

```
++ block_chain      | user | amount | timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
++ 2d37e5351196...  | 1    | 0.1    | 2014-04-09 16:21:34
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
++ 123kjhg7231k..   | 1    | 0.1    | 2014-04-08 19:33:56
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I try to assign transaction to order_id like generating a joined view from order and collector table  but I have problems when the amount and user is the same

THE PROBLEM

User places multiple order with same value

0,1 X 3

I get back transactions data from API than I identify user with the reciver address

someaddress - (here the transaction has 3 incoming confirms)

than I try to build a MySQL View as comparing

order table with collector table like joining on user and amount. When the amount and the user is same I do not get the unique transaction_id from order_table in my view

Here is the view query

```
ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`my_view`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `ci_orders_in` AS (
SELECT
  `c`.`block_chain`       AS `block_chain`,
  `c`.`assigned_user`     AS `assigned_user`,
  `c`.`incoming_amount`   AS `incoming_amount`,
  `c`.`timestamp`         AS `timestamp`,
  `c`.`type`              AS `type`,
  `c`.`category`          AS `category`,
  `c`.`import_timestamp`  AS `import_timestamp`,
  `o`.`transaction_id`    AS `transaction_id`,
  `o`.`datum`             AS `datum`,
  `o`.`status`            AS `status`,
  `o`.`convert_coin`      AS `convert_coin`,
  `o`.`convert_coin_to`   AS `convert_coin_to`,
  `o`.`amount`            AS `amount`,
  `o`.`converted_amount`  AS `converted_amount`,
  `o`.`conversion_rate`   AS `conversion_rate`,
  `o`.`user`              AS `user`,
  `o`.`units_to_transfer` AS `units_to_transfer`,
  `o`.`provision`         AS `provision`
FROM (`ci_orders` `o`
   JOIN `ci_collector` `c`
     ON ((`o`.`user` = `c`.`assigned_user`)))
WHERE (`o`.`convert_coin` = `c`.`type`)
GROUP BY `o`.`converted_amount`)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

here I should use another join which should give me the nearest timestamp but I do not get forward with it

Comment: what problem you are facing could you specify it ?

Comment: the problem is when I have for example multiple 0,1BTC transaction from the same user the transaction ID won't get as it should assigned. I have in view transactions with similar transaction_id on what should not happen

Comment: still not clear would it be possible for you to add some more sample data and the desired output you are looking at ?

Answer (score 0):

Well just looking at your view, its obvious you aren't showning us all the columns in these tables, and you've fudged the table names because the query has the column "user" in the ci_order table, but in the sample data is has the column "user_id". But since I read your question on the bitcoin SE site, and am vaguely familiar with what you're trying to do, I'm guessing you're going to want a query similar to this

[incorrect query]

**Edit:**
Sorry for not looking at the timestamps more closely. I actually bothered to load your dataset in to SQL (MS SQL 2014) this time, although I may have renamed the columns slightly. How about this? Also if you could provide details about the delay it would be helpful, such as does the order timestamp always come after the collector timestamp?

```
select *
from ci_orders
join ci_collector
    on ci_orders.user_id = ci_collector.user_id
    and ci_orders.amount = ci_collector.amount
    and ci_collector.timestamp = (
        select top 1 timestamp
        from ci_collector
        where ci_orders.user_id = ci_collector.user_id
        and ci_orders.amount = ci_collector.amount
        and ci_orders.timestamp > ci_collector.timestamp
        order by timestamp desc
    )
```

Comment: That join would not work because there is a delay between 2 timestamps

Comment: As I stated I changed some of the column names, such as making user_id match in both tables rather than be user and user_id. Also as stated it was ran on Microsoft SQL 2014, although I'd think it would work in MySQL; I dont think there is anything MS SQL specific. What error does it give you?